# Return value of redirected bash command

Tags: bash

The following script tries to create a directory and it fails because temp1 doesn't exist. I want to redirect the output with "tee." The problem is that "$?" catches the return value of "tee" which succeeds and not the value of "mkdir" which fails. How can I use "tee" but check the return value of "mkdir"

file name: ./test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir temp1/temp2 | tee test_output.txt
if [ "$?" != 0 ]; then
    echo "Command failed"
else
    echo "Command successed"
fi
```

./test.sh

mkdir: cannot create directory `temp1/temp2': No such file or directory

Command successed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you stated `bash`, you can use `PIPESTATUS`. From the `man` page:

> PIPESTATUS
>                 An array variable (see Arrays below) containing a list  of  exit
>                 status  values  from the processes in the most-recently-executed
>                 foreground pipeline (which may contain only a single command).

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir temp1/temp2 | tee test_output.txt
if [ "${PIPESTATUS[0]}" != 0 ]; then
    echo "Command failed"
else
    echo "Command succeeded"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

There are terminal dependent solutions but you can come around this issue by wrapping this command in a function.

```
create_dir() {
  { mkdir temp1/temp2 || return 1; } | tee test_output.txt
  return $?
}

create_dir
if [ "$?" != 0 ]; then
  echo "Command failed"
else
  echo "Command successed"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just use `mkdir -p`, to force creation of the directory?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is no directory temp1
Use parameter -p with mkdir:

```
mkdir -p temp1/temp2 | tee test_output.txt
```